# Use ACR as a Container Resource

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-registry

In Azure Devops you have the ability to run your pipeline in a container using "container resources", I am trying to use a container I pushed to a private acr repo but I cant for the life of me find anything that allows you to connect it. I have setup a "service connection" and allowed the pipeline to use it., this is the resource section:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: infrastructure
    image: <acr-registry>.azurecr.io/<private-image>
    env:
      ARM_ACCESS_KEY: "$(arm_access_key)"
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: "$(arm_client_id)"
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: "$(arm_client_secret)"
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: "$(arm_subscription_id)"
```

Now according to this you have to specify you want to use a "service connection" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml but in the yaml documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources) I dont see anywhere to specify the service connection to use in the resource section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use container in the build process, you can follow the official documentation:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: string  # identifier (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
    image: string  # container image name
    options: string  # arguments to pass to container at startup
    endpoint: string  # endpoint for a private container registry
    env: { string: string }  # list of environment variables to add
    ports: [ string ] # ports to expose on the container
    volumes: [ string ] # volumes to mount on the container
```

You'd need to use endpoint to specify docker registry connection you want to use

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources

Comment: would this mean that  specify the "service connection" or just the repo?

Comment: I have up voted this as it is correct, however just a note, the "endpoint" is infact the name of the "service connection" not the docker registry